# Specific divisible numbers below 1,000,000 and greater than 0 that only contain certain digits

Tags: combinatorics, decimal-expansion

How many numbers, 0 - 1,000,000 can be made up of only using 1, 4, 7, and 9, that are also divisible by either 2, 3, 7, OR 13, but are not divisible by 11?

Comment: wouldn't you actually use bases to find the amount of #s that contain 1, 4, 7, or 9s only by converting 1,000,000 base 4 (4 numbers possible) to base 10, and getting that only 4096 numbers contain 1, 4, 7, or 9s only? But I don't know how to find the second part of the problem.

Comment: I'm a 5th grader asking this question, so I know only about the bases part

Comment: @Noabji why do you have to solve this problem in $5^{th}$ grade? Unless you are enrolled in the **Ramanujan Academy for Prodigies**. Then it is alright.

Comment: Do you know the classic divisibility tests?  For example, the ones digit has to be $4$ if the number is to be divisible by $2$.  Otherwise, there are only $4^6=4096$ numbers to check.  I would just write a program or spreadsheet and count them.

Comment: Actually, I love math, I'm just wondering, I know classic divisibility rules, but I don't know how to apply them to the question